# How to define a symbol which never goes at the beginning of the next line?

Tags: symbols, punctuation

I have created a very simple symbol, and try it in the main text. What I want is this symbol never show at the beginning of a line, which means TeX(I use XeTeX) always treat it as a punctuation. How should I do that? Thanks!

Here is an very simple example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\def\DD{{\color{red} $\circ$}}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis \DD facilisis
sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet \DD mi nec
ante. 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Avoid leaving a space before `\DD`, but add `{}` after it.

Comment: This works! But what the different between a space and {} after a marco?

Comment: A space after `\DD` (and any other macro) is ignored. A space after `{}` isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is to be no space before `\DD` (that is, it is *exactly* like punctuation) then use your definition as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\DD}{{\color{red}$\circ$}}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lovbabortis\DD\ facilisis
sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet\DD\ mi nec
ante. 
\end{document}
```

If there *is* to be space before the symbol, then you can try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\DD}{\unskip~{\color{red}$\circ$}}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lovborvvv\-is \DD\ facilisis
sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet \DD\ mi nec
ante. 
\end{document
```

Answer (score 1):

Punctuation should never be separated from the preceding word (unless you're French). So

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam 
lobortis\DD{} facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra 
sollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet\DD{} mi nec ante.
```

is how you should input the code. Note `{}` in order to have a space after the symbol, because a space after `\DD` is ignored (but it isn't after `{}`).

Also the definition might be better:

```
\newcommand{\DD}{\textcolor{red}{$\circ$}}
```

With `\newcommand` you ensure that no important macro is overwritten by yours. Also `\textcolor{<color>}{<text>}` is better than `{\color{<color>}text}` if the text is short and not to be split across lines.